# Vue FrontEnd with CSRF Middleware Cake BackEnd Interaction

Tags: vue.js, security, cakephp, csrf

I am developing an app with a Vue Frontend & CakePHP 3.8 BackEnd. At this moment I am looking into setting up security before starting the actual coding of the app. One thing I am looking at is CSRF protection for my API Endpoints in Cake.

What I am doing is to have Vue retrieve the CSRF token from Cake on page load, in the created() method. Vue will then need to use the CSRF token in requests to my EndPoints. I then set a CsrfToken cookie with the retrieved token. **My CSRF Middleware compares the sent token with this cookie upon arriving on the BackEnd.** If this cookie is empty or values do not match it throws error InvalidCsrfTokenException.

**How can I add a new entry '_csrfToken' in my request params?**

This is a request made that passes CSRF Middleware check..

```
object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest) {
    trustProxy => false
    [protected] params => [
        'controller' => 'Customers',
        'action' => 'add',
        'pass' => [],
        'plugin' => null,
        '_matchedRoute' => '/{controller}/{action}/*',
        '_ext' => null,
        '_csrfToken' => '37dfc3327fe642bce88a6aca79c222921b75b752c855b683d9043d8cbbd59ab6ceb44cb3b6b3350aa54d6d1e04d011d0ccec7273150e12b58b4ef23faa47ac3b',
        '_Token' => [
            'unlockedFields' => []
        ],
        'isAjax' => false
    ]
```

This is my request at the moment.. **Problem lies in the fact that I do not have a '_csrfToken' set in $this->request->params that can be compared to the csrf Cookie..**

```
{ "controller": "Placetostays", 
"action": "apitest", 
"pass": [], 
"plugin": null, 
"_matchedRoute": "/{controller}/{action}/*", 
"_ext": null }
```

I am getting the following error when making the form POST request. Which is normal since I do not have a '_csrfToken' set in my params of my request.

**Error Stack Trace from Cake error log**

```
2020-07-16 09:25:16 Error: [Cake\Http\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException] Missing CSRF token cookie (C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware.php:230)
#0 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware.php(154): Cake\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware->_validateToken(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest))
#1 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware.php(122): Cake\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware->_validateAndUnsetTokenField(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest))
#2 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(65): Cake\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#3 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(51): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#4 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware.php(168): Cake\Http\Runner->run(Object(Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue), Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#5 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#6 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware.php(88): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#7 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(65): Cake\Routing\Middleware\AssetMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#8 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware.php(96): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#9 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(65): Cake\Error\Middleware\ErrorHandlerMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#10 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\debug_kit\src\Middleware\DebugKitMiddleware.php(53): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#11 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(65): DebugKit\Middleware\DebugKitMiddleware->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response), Object(Cake\Http\Runner))
#12 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Runner.php(51): Cake\Http\Runner->__invoke(Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#13 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Http\Server.php(97): Cake\Http\Runner->run(Object(Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue), Object(Cake\Http\ServerRequest), Object(Cake\Http\Response))
#14 C:\wampserver\www\wamp_projects\holidays_backend\webroot\index.php(40): Cake\Http\Server->run()
#15 {main}
Request URL: /placetostays/apitest
Referer URL: http://localhost:8080/formtesting
```

**Vue FrontEnd**

```
<template>
  <div id="formtest">
        
        <div id="formdiv">
          <form v-on:submit.prevent="addPlace">
            <h2>Add Placetostay</h2>
            <br>
            <input class="input" type="text" id="name" v-model="name" placeholder="name"><br>
            <input class="input" type="text" id="city" v-model="city" placeholder="city"><br>    
            <input class="input" type="number" id="postal_code" v-model="postcode" placeholder="postal code"><br> 
            <input class="input" type="text" id="street" v-model="street" placeholder="street"><br>
            <input class="input" type="number" id="house_number" v-model="housenum" placeholder="house number"><br>        
            <input class="input" type="tel" id="tel_number" v-model="telnum" placeholder="phone number"><br><br>             
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">  <button v-on:click="addtoArray">Next</button> 
          </form>           
        </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
        
    import $ from 'jquery';   
    
    var token = "";
    
    
    // you will use v-model & data on edits.. 
    export default{
       name :'formtest', 
       data(){
          return{
            user: '',
            name: '',
            city: '',
            postcode: '',
            street: '',
            housenum: '',
            telnum: '',
            post_data: '',
            errors: [],
            data: [],
            token: '',
            total_payload: [],
            }
        },
       
       methods: {
            
            addPlace(){
                 
               this.data[0] = this.name;
               this.data[1] = this.city;   
               this.data[2] = this.postcode;
               this.data[3] = this.street;     
               this.data[4] = this.housenum;
               this.data[5] = this.telnum;   

               // THE QUESTION: HOW DO I SET THIS COOKIE IN MY PARAMS['_csrfToken']?
                        
               this.total_payload.push(this.data);   
               console.log(this.total_payload);            
                        
                        
               var url = 'http://wampprojects/holidays_backend/placetostays/apitest/';
               // this accesses the pass parameter in $this->request->params, does not create new params parameter.. 
               // var url = 'http://wampprojects/holidays_backend/placetostays/apitest/csrftoken:bar';

               // in order for CSRF Middleware & Security Component to work, need to be able to access request parameters 
               // _csrfToken & Token values.. 
               fetch(url, {
                   method: 'POST',
                   mode: 'cors',
                   headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                          },
                   body: JSON.stringify(this.total_payload),
                        })
                   .then(response => response.json())
                   .then(json_data => this.post_data = json_data) 
                   .catch(error => {

                           console.log("error");

                        });                  

                   this.name = this.city = this.postcode = this.street = this.housenum = this.telnum = '';                        
                        
                    } 
                } 
            },           
       },
       
       created(){
           
            fetch('http://wampprojects/holidays_backend/placetostays/', {
              method: 'GET',
              mode: 'cors',
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',             
              },
            })
            .then(response => response.json())  
            .then(json_data => this.token = json_data) 
            .then(json_data => {
              
               token = json_data;
                // need to initialize the session for when no one is logged in yet..
                // this will be very important!!!  
                this.$session.start();   
                console.log(this.$session.getAll());   
                
                this.$cookies.set('theme', 'default');
                // when to set the cookie value? 
                this.$cookies.set('csrfToken', token['token']);                
                
            })    
            .catch(error => {

               console.log("error");

            }); 
       },
    }
    
</script>
```

**Cake Controller Backend**

```
public function apitest(){

    $data = $this->request->data;        
    $sendback = "";   
    
    // this check is necessary, will otherwise cause problem at startup 
    if($data){
                    
        // where exactly does the middleware perform this test? when the call arrives @ backend..  
        
        foreach($data as $newplace):
            
            $new_placetostay = $this->Placetostays->newEntity();
            $new_placetostay->name = $newplace[0];
            $new_placetostay->city = $newplace[1]; 
            $new_placetostay->postal_code = $newplace[2];
            $new_placetostay->street = $newplace[3]; 
            $new_placetostay->number = $newplace[4];
            $new_placetostay->tel_number = $newplace[5];   
            
            $this->Placetostays->save($new_placetostay);
            
        endforeach;
                     
    }

    // no automatic view, only data returned
    $this->autoRender = false;
    
    $this->response = $this->response->cors($this->request)
        ->allowOrigin(['http://localhost:8080'])
        ->allowMethods(['GET', 'POST'])
        ->allowHeaders(['*'])
        ->allowCredentials()
        ->exposeHeaders(['Link'])
        ->maxAge(300)
        ->build();          
    
    return $this->response
    ->withType('application/json')
    ->withStringBody(json_encode($parameters));            
    
}
```

**EDIT: I am trying to create a separate routing scope for controller 'placetostays', but it still gives me a CSRF error when making an API call to this controller. What am I doing wrong?**

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->registerMiddleware('csrf', new CsrfProtectionMiddleware([
        'httpOnly' => true
    ]));
    $routes->applyMiddleware('csrf');
    
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);
    $routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);
    
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
    
});

Router::scope('/apitest', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    
    // in this controller I want to have JWT enabled 
    // I would expect CSRF middleware here not to throw an error, since I do not load it for this scope.. 
    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the wrong setup.  You are developing vuejs on port 8080 and you are running cakephp on a separate environment. Hosts are different from a csrf perspective.  You should either:

1. run the vuejs compiled version in cake templating and load all frontend assets as per cakephp documentation.  While this approach works it's outdated and lame since you would have to adapt and copy every time you compile vuejs and you will loose the ability of the development server.  You could still use your setup and scope a route for development purposes in CakePhp that does not load the CsrfMiddleware.  Either way I suggest you do the follwing:
2. run both, cakephp and vuejs on their own environments and substitute csrf for jwt.  There is a dedicated cakephp plugin (https://github.com/ADmad/cakephp-jwt-auth) that is mentioned in the documentation.  You should create a scoped route in cake that does not load the CsrfMiddleWare and load the JWT plugin.  Configure authentication accordingly in your Controller and your backend should be good to go.  On your Vuejs side you need obtain a token, either through to set the Authorization Header

Csrf tokens and jwt are different and serve different purposes.  Csrf is supposed to work on same host.  This means within your wamp server frontend and backend are expected to be on the same host.  Your setup doesn't.

Jwt tokens are built to be running on either, same host or different hosts.  Each token can be associated to a user o can be anonymous where applicable.

POST, PUT, PATCH and DELETE Http methods should always be protected.  JWT is a better approach since you would be handling decoupled frontend and backends which is more "modern".

Feel free to ask anything

**EDIT**

in routes.php add:

```
Router::prefix('api', function(RouteBuilder $routes) {
$routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

Create src/Controllers/Api/AppController.php and add:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Api;
use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Event\Event;
class AppController extends Controller
{
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');

$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ]
            ],
            'ADmad/JwtAuth.Jwt' => [
                'userModel' => 'Users',
                'fields' => [
                    'email' => 'id'
                ],

                'parameter' => 'token',

                // Boolean indicating whether the "sub" claim of JWT payload
                // should be used to query the Users model and get user info.
                // If set to `false` JWT's payload is directly returned.
                'queryDatasource' => true,
            ]
        ],
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login',
            'prefix' => 'api'
        ],
         // If unauthorized, return them to page they were just on
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer()
    ]);
}
}
```

Here is what is going on:

You prefix a route in your router.php.  CakePhp infers it should load namespace App\Controllers\Api\AppController.php.  You initialize the class with your Jwt information, here it assumes you are using email as username for authentication, you can change all of these based on your needs.

Note that you are also declaring a fallback route in routes.php.  Every request pointed at api/* will resolve for a controller, i.e. 'api/users' assumes that src/Controllers/Api/UsersController.php exists, otherwise throwing a missing Controller exception.  Inside each of your controllers, within the namespace App\Controllers\Api now you can control access to your different views.  For example, in src/Controlelrs/Api/UsersController.php you need to add allow constraint to Auth object and include the routes that will not require JWT auth:

```
$this->Auth->allow(['register', 'token']);
```

this means api/users/register and api/users/token routes are set to override the JWT auth constraint, which makes sense because usually you will need an endpoint for users to claim the JWT token and you would want users to register.

Comment: Hello Luis, thank you for your time and answer! I am not working today, will review this tomorrow and check out the documentation of this. If I have any more questions I will certainly ask.. Really thanks!

Comment: I have looked into it and have decided - as you suggested - to implement JWT for /api routes in each controller. I tried creating a separate scoped route for the /api extension, but do not find the right syntax to do it.. Have edited the question. What am I missing? Thank you for your time..

Comment: Hi Luis, I have taken your advice and have started implementing JWT security on my API EndPoints. It has taken some time, and had to focus on something else for a couple of months, but have finally implemented it. I use the plugin, but do not succeed in using the retrieved token in subsequent requests.. I have created a new question for this, because it is a question on the implementation. And it was a lot of text.. If you have the time I would really appreciate it if you could take a look.. Thanks and take care!